# Rails 4.2 How to eager load/preload associated objects with dynamic condition for them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, eager-loading

I develop engine for Ruby on Rails project. Here you can see how I solve the problem of eager loading associated objects with dynamic condition:

My models:

```
#version.rb  
class Version < ActiveRecord::Base
 class <<self
     attr_accessor :type
     attr_accessor :id
 end
 validates :name, :description, presence: true
 belongs_to :package
 has_many :clustervers,:dependent => :destroy
 has_many :accesses,:dependent => :destroy
 has_many :user_accesses,-> { where(  "who_type= ? AND  who_id=?",Version.type,Version.id) }, class_name: "Access"

end
 #Access.rb
class Access < ActiveRecord::Base
 enum status: [:request,:allowed,:denied]
 validates :version_id, :user_id,presence: true
 validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:version_id]
 belongs_to :version
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :who, :polymorphic => true

end
```

Controller:

```
def show
  Version.type="User"
  Version.id=2
  @package = Package.find(params[:id])
   @versions = Version.page(params[:page]).per(2).includes({clustervers: :core_cluster},:user_accesses)
   .where(package_id:params[:id])
end
```

View:

```
  for version in @versions
                tr 
                    td  #{version.name} 
                    td  #{version.description}
                    td  #{version.r_up} 
                    td  #{version.r_down}





                        -if version.user_accesses.take
                            p   show attributes
                        -else
                            p   no access
                    td
```

Are there more convenient methods to do this? Is it possible to do this using raw SQL statments? 
I need something to generate SQL condition like this: 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ... ON a.id=b.id and CONDITION